# Creating CMFCDesktopAlertWnd Control in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, desktop-application

MSDN contains an example for creating a desktop alert window:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983515.aspx

The sample code starts with the following declaration.

```
CMFCDesktopAlertWnd* pPopup = new CMFCDesktopAlertWnd;
```

When I use it in my code, the compiler complains

```
'CMFCDesktopAlertWnd' : no appropriate default constructor available
```

This is the complete source code of my application.
(I created an empty Win32 project in Visual Studio and set 
the **Use MFC in a Shared DLL** option on the **Property | General** page.)

```
#include <afxwin.h>
#include <afxDesktopAlertDialog.h>

class Notifier : public CWinApp
{
public:
        virtual BOOL InitInstance();
};

BOOL Notifier::InitInstance()
{
        CMFCDesktopAlertWnd* pPopup = new CMFCDesktopAlertWnd;
        return TRUE;
}

Notifier myApp;
```

What am I doing wrong?
The effect is the same in VS Express 2008 and the full version of VS 2010.

Answer (score 0):

- Are you using VS 2008 SP1? (The service pack is important)
- Are you including the proper headers in stdafx.h? More specifically, you need

  #include < afxext.h >

  #include < afxcontrolbars.h >

to be able to use MFC Next (feature pack) classes.

It won't work on VS Express anyway because that doesn't include MFC.